# Error when i insert fields into mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from products;
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| productID | productCode | name       | quantity | price | supplierID |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|      1001 | PEN         | Pen Red    |     5000 |  1.35 |          0 |
|      1002 | pen         | pen blue   |     8000 |  1.38 |          0 |
|      1003 | pen         | pen black  |     8000 |  1.38 |          0 |
|      1004 | Pen         | Pen Yellow |     1020 |  1.44 |          0 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

I try below

```
mysql> INSERT INTO products  VALUES (NULL, 'PENCIL','PEN CYAN', 4333, 1.88);
```

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Why is there error? i insert NULL to auto_increment column but there is error? why

Comment: `INSERT INTO products(productCode, ...)VALUES (NULL, 'PENCIL','PEN CYAN', 4333, 1.88);` always specify columns you insert into.

Comment: You insert only 5 values, while your table has 6 columns.

Comment: The answer is 
INSERT INTO products(productCode, ...)VALUES (NULL, 'PENCIL','PEN CYAN', 4333, 1.88);      

I thought i can insert a row without the need to specify column
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1001, 'PEN', 'Pen Red', 5000, 1.23);
It works but the primary key has to be correct by plus 1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the supplierID value.
This error is telling you that the number of columns (6)
does not match the number of values (5)

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to specify the columns you want to insert to if you don't insert into all of your columns

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`productCode`, `name`, `quantity`, `price`)  VALUES ('PENCIL','PEN CYAN', 4333, 1.88);
```